# Make "super/window" as compose key in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

Somehow on my new *X230t Lenovo Thinkpad*, Ubuntu 13.10 only lets me have the following options as the compose key:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Right Win</kbd>,  <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>

I really don't care for Unity's functions using <kbd>Super</kbd>. I would like to set this as my compose key. Is there any way to manage this?

**UPDATE:** This solution had been working like a charm for me, until today when Ubuntu did a fateful update. I looked at the d-conf editor for the entry below. It still shows `compose:lwin` as an option. But Left Window is no longer available as an option in the keyboard settings. Any suggestions? (I am using Ubuntu 14.04 now)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this through the `dconf-editor`. If you do not already have it installed, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Navigate to *org* >> *gnome* >> *desktop* >> *input-sources*

Click in the setting, `xkb-options` and add `'compose:lwin'` inside the square brackets. The single quotes are required.

If other options are already there, the order does not matter; but separate the options with a comma: `'compose:lwin','other:option'`

For those who looks for a command line solution (without installing dconf-editor) you can use:

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options 
@as []
```

This will tell you the current state of the key. Now you can insert your own:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options ['compose:lwin']
```

This command as above worked fine for me, but @bryce reports that he needed double quotes, as in:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:lwin']"
```

Comment: I needed to double quote the value.
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:lwin']"