# German special characters on US/Hebrew keyboard

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

Israeli keyboards come in US layout with Hebrew added in a different color, and toggling between character sets is usually done with Alt_Shift.

For the German special characters there used to be Alt_Number combinations under DOS and different Alt_Number combinations under Windows, and also different combinations in the different word processors. For quite sometime, I have been using Ubuntu and yet another set of number combinations - Ctrl_Shift_u_df = ß, Ctrl_Shift_u_c4 = Ä, Ctrl_Shift_u_e4 = ä, Ctrl_Shift_u_d6 = Ö, Ctrl_Shift_u_f6 = ö, Ctrl_Shift_u_dc = Ü, Ctrl_Shift_u_fc = ü, all found [here](http://www.hermit.org/Linux/ComposeKeys.html).

And now comes ubuntu 13.10, Hebrew-English toggling is suddenly tricky, and gone are Ä, ä, Ö, ö, while Ü, ü, and ß are there as they were, but the first key typed after one of them does not show on the screen, I hope does not do some invisible mischief.

I understand that ubuntu 14.04 is less than two months away and will probably provide a satisfactory answer to everybody's complaints , but maybe there is some Specialkey_Number combo out there that everybody except me and the online complainers already knows?
Changing to German keyboard layout is not an option - easy to set up but too hard to live with. I tried, years ago.

Comment: The behaviour of these key combination is mostly governed by your keyboard settings. These can be found under "system settings >> keyboard >> layout settings". Could it be that this setting is currently different? I'm not familiar with the German settings but there is for instance a big difference between Enlgish (US) and English (US, international with dead keys)

Comment: Difficult theme. 13.10 had (and still has) a very big regression with multi-language users, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322. I have almost decided to try to write my personal layout, but it's a bit complex. You can find links at the end of  http://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395