# What's the opposite of setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps?

Tags: keyboard, capslock

Normally I have caps lock to be a control key.

> setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps

makes that happen, but I can't remember where I got it from or find any docs (`man setxkbmap` is singularly unhelpful )

Can anyone tell me the command to put it back to how it normally is, or at least point me at the docs that tell me what `-option ctrl:nocaps` actually does?

Comment: To put it back to how it normally is, just `setxkbmap -option` works  for me.

Comment: Kinda funny when a question is actually the answer of my search. Hehe, thanks! :)

Answer (score 33):

When you have already set something, you might need to clear before setting something new.

To unset:

> To put it back to how it normally is, just `setxkbmap -option` works for me. – Emanuele Natale Sep 8 '14 at 19:29

Example: I was using `setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps` so that I could deal with (i.e. unset) caps lock after it got set by random quirks.  Today I wanted nocaps, but could not set it because the other setting was still active.  I used the command above and then I was able to use `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`

Comment: You may want to `setxkbmap -print` first, to see your existing options. If you have several options set and are only looking to drop one you won't have to guess at what they were. Also, if (like me) you're trying to unset capslock that "randomly" turned on you might notice that you have `shift:both_capslock` set and realize how it got turned on.

Answer (score 23):

Would be really nice to find a complete, readable documentation where is explained how the keyboard mechanism works in Ubuntu and how to locally override it (and how it interacts with layout switching).

I am under the suspicion that there is [really few people really understanding it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322) (I remember a famous quote of Stephen Hawkings, methinks,  about time); [I have collected a bit of links](https://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395) in another answer but still, no general how-to.

Basically you should chase all the definitions for your keyboard starting from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` --- if your keyboard is `us`, substitute as needed; there are a lot of options and includes in it, it seems that most of the modifiers keys are in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base`, where you can find:

```
caps:none             =       +capslock(none)
caps:ctrl_modifier    =       +capslock(ctrl_modifier)
ctrl:nocaps           =       +ctrl(nocaps)
ctrl:lctrl_meta       =       +ctrl(lctrl_meta)
ctrl:swapcaps         =       +ctrl(swapcaps)
```

and in `xorg.lst`:

```
ctrl:nocaps    Caps Lock as Ctrl 
...
caps:capslock        Caps Lock toggles normal capitalization of alphabetic characters
```

among gazillion other things. So what that mean, and what other options you have, are probably dependent on your layout, but you can try to guess something looking there. 
For example I would try

```
setxkbmap -option caps:capslock
```

to revert it.

Now, what they exactly mean, how do you enable it (via `control center` -> `keyboard` or `language`, via `gnome-tweak-tool`, command line, init scripts), how to make them impervious to a layout switch, if they work or not (I am *unable* to disable caps-lock and make it so across layout switches), is another matter.

If anyone can fill in the answer, please do that. I was used to tweak my keyboard with `xmodmap`, I understand this is superceded, but would it be really nice to have an howto to how to tweak your keyboard...

Comment: Despite all the upvotes, this actually doesn't work. Previously set options seem to override later options, and you can set multiple conflicting options without the earlier one being deleted.

Comment: @pydsigner sorry ---  It worked for me when I posted this, but again, I wouldn't be surprised if something changed. I gave up on having multiple layouts, and I still think that `xkb` configuration is black magic in general and sheer luck in Ubuntu...

Comment: 'xbd' in the paths above is a typo and should be xkb

Comment: @AaronSkomra, thanks, I think I fixed it. You can also edit the post yourself, no problem!