# xmodmap loose custom settinfs in some cases

Tags: xmodmap

All.

I'm remap Cmd key behaviour to act like a Ctrl with xmodmap. All works fine, but in some cases xmodmap loose my custom settings and return to defaults.
I.e. when i'm pressing Ctrl-Space (change keyboard layout in my case) or when i'm focus Skype chat window. Any suggestion why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: With all due respect, keyboard handling is a mess. `xomodmap` is deprecated and get reset a lot of times; I was not able to find instructions on a clean way to modify your keyboard layout. See http://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395 and if you find a recipe or clear documentation, please share.

Comment: BTW, every time when i switch to skype window two lines appears in X.log
[ 56268.257] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-DB7B5C848A0555E14167C144FBC656D0EAE44A25.xkm
[ 56270.997] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm

May be it causes xmodmap reset?