# Using Xmodmap, my shift lock now acts as both a shift lock and a compose key. I just want it to work as a compose key. What can I do?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have two Xmodmap files. First one:

```
keycode   8 =
keycode   9 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
keycode  10 = ampersand 1 ampersand 1 bar exclamdown bar
keycode  11 = eacute 2 eacute 2 at oneeighth at
keycode  12 = quotedbl 3 quotedbl 3 numbersign sterling numbersign
keycode  13 = apostrophe 4 apostrophe 4 onequarter dollar onequarter
keycode  14 = parenleft 5 parenleft 5 onehalf threeeighths onehalf
keycode  15 = section 6 section 6 asciicircum fiveeighths asciicircum
keycode  16 = egrave 7 egrave 7 braceleft seveneighths braceleft
keycode  17 = exclam 8 exclam 8 bracketleft trademark bracketleft
keycode  18 = ccedilla 9 ccedilla 9 braceleft plusminus braceleft
keycode  19 = agrave 0 agrave 0 braceright degree braceright
keycode  20 = parenright degree parenright degree backslash questiondown backslash
keycode  21 = minus underscore minus underscore dead_cedilla dead_ogonek dead_cedilla
keycode  22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace
keycode  23 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  24 = a A a A at Greek_OMEGA at
keycode  25 = z Z z Z lstroke Lstroke lstroke
keycode  26 = e E e E EuroSign cent EuroSign
keycode  27 = r R r R paragraph registered paragraph
keycode  28 = t T t T tslash Tslash tslash
keycode  29 = y Y y Y leftarrow yen leftarrow
keycode  30 = u U u U downarrow uparrow downarrow
keycode  31 = i I i I rightarrow idotless rightarrow
keycode  32 = o O o O oe OE oe
keycode  33 = p P p P thorn THORN thorn
keycode  34 = dead_circumflex dead_diaeresis dead_circumflex dead_diaeresis bracketleft dead_abovering bracketleft
keycode  35 = dollar asterisk dollar asterisk bracketright dead_macron bracketright
keycode  36 = Return NoSymbol Return
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode  38 = q Q q Q ae AE ae
keycode  39 = s S s S ssharp section ssharp
keycode  40 = d D d D eth ETH eth
keycode  41 = f F f F dstroke ordfeminine dstroke
keycode  42 = g G g G eng ENG eng
keycode  43 = h H h H hstroke Hstroke hstroke
keycode  44 = j J j J dead_hook dead_horn dead_hook
keycode  45 = k K k K kra ampersand kra
keycode  46 = l L l L lstroke Lstroke lstroke
keycode  47 = m M m M dead_acute dead_doubleacute dead_acute
keycode  48 = ugrave percent ugrave percent dead_acute dead_caron dead_acute
keycode  49 = twosuperior threesuperior twosuperior threesuperior notsign notsign notsign
keycode  50 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode  51 = mu sterling mu sterling dead_grave dead_breve dead_grave
keycode  52 = w W w W guillemotleft less guillemotleft
keycode  53 = x X x X guillemotright greater guillemotright
keycode  54 = c C c C cent copyright cent
keycode  55 = v V v V leftdoublequotemark leftsinglequotemark leftdoublequotemark
keycode  56 = b B b B rightdoublequotemark rightsinglequotemark rightdoublequotemark
keycode  57 = n N n N n N n
keycode  58 = comma question comma question dead_cedilla masculine dead_cedilla
keycode  59 = semicolon period semicolon period horizconnector multiply horizconnector
keycode  60 = colon slash colon slash periodcentered division periodcentered
keycode  61 = equal plus equal plus dead_tilde dead_abovedot dead_tilde
keycode  62 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
keycode  63 = KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply KP_Multiply XF86ClearGrab
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode  65 = space NoSymbol space
keycode  66 = Multi_key NoSymbol Multi_key
keycode  67 = F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 F1 XF86Switch_VT_1
keycode  68 = F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 F2 XF86Switch_VT_2
keycode  69 = F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 F3 XF86Switch_VT_3
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
keycode  71 = F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 F5 XF86Switch_VT_5
keycode  72 = F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 F6 XF86Switch_VT_6
keycode  73 = F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 F7 XF86Switch_VT_7
keycode  74 = F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 F8 XF86Switch_VT_8
keycode  75 = F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 F9 XF86Switch_VT_9
keycode  76 = F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 F10 XF86Switch_VT_10
keycode  77 = Num_Lock NoSymbol Num_Lock
keycode  78 = Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock
keycode  79 = KP_Home KP_7 KP_Home KP_7
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode  81 = KP_Prior KP_9 KP_Prior KP_9
keycode  82 = KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract KP_Subtract XF86Prev_VMode
keycode  83 = KP_Left KP_4 KP_Left KP_4
keycode  84 = KP_Begin KP_5 KP_Begin KP_5
keycode  85 = KP_Right KP_6 KP_Right KP_6
keycode  86 = KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add KP_Add XF86Next_VMode
keycode  87 = KP_End KP_1 KP_End KP_1
keycode  88 = KP_Down KP_2 KP_Down KP_2
keycode  89 = KP_Next KP_3 KP_Next KP_3
keycode  90 = KP_Insert KP_0 KP_Insert KP_0
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode  93 =
keycode  94 = less greater less greater backslash backslash backslash
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
keycode  96 = F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 F12 XF86Switch_VT_12
keycode  97 =
keycode  98 = Katakana NoSymbol Katakana
keycode  99 = Hiragana NoSymbol Hiragana
keycode 100 = Henkan_Mode NoSymbol Henkan_Mode
keycode 101 = Hiragana_Katakana NoSymbol Hiragana_Katakana
keycode 102 = Muhenkan NoSymbol Muhenkan
keycode 103 =
keycode 104 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 106 = KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide KP_Divide XF86Ungrab
keycode 107 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 109 = Linefeed NoSymbol Linefeed
keycode 110 = Home NoSymbol Home
keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Up
keycode 112 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Left
keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right
keycode 115 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down
keycode 117 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 118 = Insert NoSymbol Insert
keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
keycode 120 =
keycode 121 = XF86AudioMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMute
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
keycode 124 = XF86PowerOff NoSymbol XF86PowerOff
keycode 125 = KP_Equal NoSymbol KP_Equal
keycode 126 = plusminus NoSymbol plusminus
keycode 127 = Pause Break Pause Break
keycode 128 = XF86LaunchA NoSymbol XF86LaunchA
keycode 129 = KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal KP_Decimal
keycode 130 = Hangul NoSymbol Hangul
keycode 131 = Hangul_Hanja NoSymbol Hangul_Hanja
keycode 132 =
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 135 = U0394 NoSymbol U0394
keycode 136 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 137 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 138 = SunProps NoSymbol SunProps
keycode 139 = Undo NoSymbol Undo
keycode 140 = SunFront NoSymbol SunFront
keycode 141 = XF86Copy NoSymbol XF86Copy
keycode 142 = XF86Open NoSymbol XF86Open
keycode 143 = XF86Paste NoSymbol XF86Paste
keycode 144 = Find NoSymbol Find
keycode 145 = XF86Cut NoSymbol XF86Cut
keycode 146 = Help NoSymbol Help
keycode 147 = XF86MenuKB NoSymbol XF86MenuKB
keycode 148 = XF86Calculator NoSymbol XF86Calculator
keycode 149 =
keycode 150 = XF86Sleep NoSymbol XF86Sleep
keycode 151 = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp
keycode 152 = XF86Explorer NoSymbol XF86Explorer
keycode 153 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 154 =
keycode 155 = XF86Xfer NoSymbol XF86Xfer
keycode 156 = XF86Launch1 NoSymbol XF86Launch1
keycode 157 = XF86Launch2 NoSymbol XF86Launch2
keycode 158 = XF86WWW NoSymbol XF86WWW
keycode 159 = XF86DOS NoSymbol XF86DOS
keycode 160 = XF86ScreenSaver NoSymbol XF86ScreenSaver
keycode 161 =
keycode 162 = XF86RotateWindows NoSymbol XF86RotateWindows
keycode 163 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 164 = XF86Favorites NoSymbol XF86Favorites
keycode 165 = XF86MyComputer NoSymbol XF86MyComputer
keycode 166 = XF86Back NoSymbol XF86Back
keycode 167 = XF86Forward NoSymbol XF86Forward
keycode 168 =
keycode 169 = XF86Eject NoSymbol XF86Eject
keycode 170 = XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject XF86Eject
keycode 171 = XF86AudioNext NoSymbol XF86AudioNext
keycode 172 = XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause XF86AudioPlay XF86AudioPause
keycode 173 = XF86AudioPrev NoSymbol XF86AudioPrev
keycode 174 = XF86AudioStop XF86Eject XF86AudioStop XF86Eject
keycode 175 = XF86AudioRecord NoSymbol XF86AudioRecord
keycode 176 = XF86AudioRewind NoSymbol XF86AudioRewind
keycode 177 = XF86Phone NoSymbol XF86Phone
keycode 178 =
keycode 179 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 180 = XF86HomePage NoSymbol XF86HomePage
keycode 181 = XF86Reload NoSymbol XF86Reload
keycode 182 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 183 =
keycode 184 =
keycode 185 = XF86ScrollUp NoSymbol XF86ScrollUp
keycode 186 = XF86ScrollDown NoSymbol XF86ScrollDown
keycode 187 = parenleft NoSymbol parenleft
keycode 188 = parenright NoSymbol parenright
keycode 189 = XF86New NoSymbol XF86New
keycode 190 = Redo NoSymbol Redo
keycode 191 = XF86Tools NoSymbol XF86Tools
keycode 192 = XF86Launch5 NoSymbol XF86Launch5
keycode 193 = XF86Launch6 NoSymbol XF86Launch6
keycode 194 = XF86Launch7 NoSymbol XF86Launch7
keycode 195 = XF86Launch8 NoSymbol XF86Launch8
keycode 196 = XF86Launch9 NoSymbol XF86Launch9
keycode 197 =
keycode 198 = XF86AudioMicMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMicMute
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
keycode 200 = XF86TouchpadOn NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOn
keycode 201 = XF86TouchpadOff NoSymbol XF86TouchpadOff
keycode 202 =
keycode 203 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
keycode 205 = NoSymbol Meta_L NoSymbol Meta_L
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 207 = NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L
keycode 208 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 209 = XF86AudioPause NoSymbol XF86AudioPause
keycode 210 = XF86Launch3 NoSymbol XF86Launch3
keycode 211 = XF86Launch4 NoSymbol XF86Launch4
keycode 212 = XF86LaunchB NoSymbol XF86LaunchB
keycode 213 = XF86Suspend NoSymbol XF86Suspend
keycode 214 = XF86Close NoSymbol XF86Close
keycode 215 = XF86AudioPlay NoSymbol XF86AudioPlay
keycode 216 = XF86AudioForward NoSymbol XF86AudioForward
keycode 217 =
keycode 218 = Print NoSymbol Print
keycode 219 =
keycode 220 = XF86WebCam NoSymbol XF86WebCam
keycode 221 =
keycode 222 =
keycode 223 = XF86Mail NoSymbol XF86Mail
keycode 224 = XF86Messenger NoSymbol XF86Messenger
keycode 225 = XF86Search NoSymbol XF86Search
keycode 226 = XF86Go NoSymbol XF86Go
keycode 227 = XF86Finance NoSymbol XF86Finance
keycode 228 = XF86Game NoSymbol XF86Game
keycode 229 = XF86Shop NoSymbol XF86Shop
keycode 230 =
keycode 231 = Cancel NoSymbol Cancel
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
keycode 234 = XF86AudioMedia NoSymbol XF86AudioMedia
keycode 235 = XF86Display NoSymbol XF86Display
keycode 236 = XF86KbdLightOnOff NoSymbol XF86KbdLightOnOff
keycode 237 = XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
keycode 239 = XF86Send NoSymbol XF86Send
keycode 240 = XF86Reply NoSymbol XF86Reply
keycode 241 = XF86MailForward NoSymbol XF86MailForward
keycode 242 = XF86Save NoSymbol XF86Save
keycode 243 = XF86Documents NoSymbol XF86Documents
keycode 244 = XF86Battery NoSymbol XF86Battery
keycode 245 = XF86Bluetooth NoSymbol XF86Bluetooth
keycode 246 = XF86WLAN NoSymbol XF86WLAN
keycode 247 =
keycode 248 =
keycode 249 =
keycode 250 =
keycode 251 =
keycode 252 =
keycode 253 =
keycode 254 =
keycode 255 =
```

Second one:

```
clear Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Multi_key
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Belgian Dutch-language AZERTY by the way, for might that be needed to solve it. **And I am using Xubuntu, so I can't change compose key/caps lock behaviours in the control center.**

Comment: `xmodmap` works only partially on Ubuntu, which uses the `xkb` system. You are probably better served by trying to define a new layout, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/422650/map-altgr-a-z-and-shift-altgr-a-z-to-greek-letter and the links in my answer... I do not exactly know how to disable Caps Lock and making it a Compose, but you should be able to find them... Other recent question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/482825/using-setxkbmap-for-a-simple-remap-similar-to-xmodmap/483995#483995

Answer (score 0):

In the new world, keyboard is managed by `xkb` which is not 100% compatible with `xmodmap`. See for example [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482825/using-setxkbmap-for-a-simple-remap-similar-to-xmodmap) and [this answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395). To change the modifier keys the best way is to go through the configuration utilities.

I can answer for Ubuntu Gnome --- you should be able to see the equivalent in Unity.

As incredible as it can seems, it has to be set in two different places with two different programs --- given that to "simplify" the settings interface part of the switches have been moved to the `gnome-tweak-tool` application.

Step 1: open `gnome-tweak-tool`, and in **Typing**, set:

Note that by default the menu option says **disabled**, that means that no tweak is done to Caps Lock, not that it is disabled --- to disable it you have to choose "Caps Lock is disabled". (no comment)

[image]

Step 2: go to control center -> keyboard -> typing and choose Menu as CapsLock

[image]

Comment: I can do the first thing, but not the second, because I am using Xubuntu so I don't have the GNOME control center.

Comment: I installed gnome Tweaks. But theres no "Typing" option in Tweaks. Below ¨ Top Bar" the option in the left menu is "Windows". I actually have all the options that you first pic shows, except "Typing". Iḿ using last Ubuntu version (18.x)... Any idea why is that so... ? Do I need to activate something elsewhere for that option to show up or something?

Comment: @Martec In 18.04 there is a "Keyboard & Mouse" section in tweaks where you can find "Compose Key". Chose that as Caps Lock and it should be done. I am not sure because I am using my own keyboard map, see http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/

Comment: Thans @Rmano, good to know I'm not missing something. Yet, I was hoping to find something that explained why changing `Caps Lock behaviour` options in   `Additional Layout Options` , below  `Compose Key`,  doesn't work (nothing is changed even though selection remains). I have seen some questions about this, but  haven't found a solution and thought this could be related with that... So what I really want to do is having Caps Lock to only activate uppercase (not deactivate, that'd be Shift).  Any idea on making `Caps Lock behavior` functional?

Comment: @Martec --- sorry, I have tried but no idea (and fortunately my "Caps Lock as compose" is still ok. Could be that some command line trick with `setxkbmap` can do the trick...  Maybe you can file a bug report...