# Gnome tweak tool is unable to disable caps lock

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool, capslock

I just installed this because xmodmap keeps resetting and I need to use caps lock as backspace but selecting this option in gnome-tweak-tool gives me normal caps lock behaviour AND caps lock behaviour. Selecting "Caps lock is disabled" does nothing.

I have the minimak layout installed by evdev modification but I hope this isn't the problem?

Comment: I have CapsLock set as Compose and it works ok following http://askubuntu.com/a/484749/16395. Using US international layout though.