# Keyboard Layout. Alt GR +

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

So I moved from Windows to Ubuntu. I looked around but couldn't find it.
I'd need to add keybindings:

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> woult bind to `õ`. <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> to `Ü` etc.

How would one achieve this monstrosity?

Comment: Maybe this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395 can help. Xmodmap should sort of work, bit it is really deprecated by `xkb`

Comment: Looks like "for people who have time, there is linux, for the rest of us there is windows" moment for me.

Comment: It's not *so* difficult. once you get a shot at it. But yes, a graphical tool for personalizing the keyboard would be welcome --- this is the good and bad of open-source. Someone must do it, for free, or you have to pay for it (at least partially).

Comment: Friend has Graphical tool in xubuntu. but I'm cracking on http://hack.org/mc/writings/xkb.html to find what i'm looking for, haven't gotten the time. Programm enough at work to get my head dizzy with 3rd pary documentation :D, come home... not gonna like reading much more!

Answer (score 0):

This monstrosity is achieved by a tool called Xmodmap. You will need to create a file, called `.Xmodmap` in your home directory. Search over the net for instructions on how to fill it.
Many xmodmap manuals tell you to run it manually - you don't need to, the file will be applied on relogin automatically.