# Xmodmap unlisted characters. Is there a way to add them?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, button

I would like to type some specific characters after using xmodmap to map them.

For example, the ⅒ character (Numeric value: 0x2152).

I would like to change a keyboard button to type ⅒ like so

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 56 = 0x2152"    #Would like it to type "⅒"
```

However, this does not work. An example using the pound sign works:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 56 = 0x023"     #Types "#"
```

Is there anything I can do to get this to work, or who can I contact to get this to work?

Comment: Interestingly, I see a square here, but if I paste the character into another program, I see the 1/10 sign. What is the actual character?

Comment: It is indeed the 1/10 sign.
Maybe your browser is using a font that does not support such character?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`xmodmap -e "keycode 61 = U2152" # ⅒`

Works for me.

Like [ByteCommander](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601692/xmodmap-unlisted-characters-is-there-a-way-to-add-them/601698#comment839727_601698) said already the `U` stands for Unicode.
More Information are available in the [man page of xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xmodmap.1.html#contenttoc4).

Comment: Although the answer solved the question, you could still improve it a bit (and keep in mind for future answers) by adding some explanations or detail about what you suggest. I don't know if this is correct here, but you could have written for example that the "U" is needed before the character code to tell xmodmap it is a Unicode character (just guessing).

Comment: @ByteCommander: You are right guessing the `U` stands for Unicode. I Updated the answer.

Comment: Unicodes are usually displayed as U+2152, which is what I tried, but it didn't work. So taking out the plus is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

And once you used the [correct answer by juAron](https://askubuntu.com/a/601698/16395), Are you sure you have a font for it? With a [Compose Key](http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/compose/), I can type it for example in LO writer eith the Libertine font as <kbd>Compose</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>10</kbd>:

[image: LO output]

...but it will not work on the terminal:

[image: on terminal]

Unless I use the correct font (Notice this is a big character, it makes strange things on monospaced fonts:)

[image]

(PD: `xmodmap` is deprecated; [see here for more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422650/map-altgr-a-z-and-shift-altgr-a-z-to-greek-letter)).

Comment: Yes, I did have a working font for it, after using juAron's command, it worked.
Thank you either way!