# Ubuntu 15.04: How can I make Capslock + æ,ø,å type these letters, with an English keyboard?

Tags: 15.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, customization

I've been googling for hours, and I really can't seem to find an answer to what I'm trying to do here.

So basically what I wanna do is use an English keyboard, but make it so that when I press Capslock + either æ ø or å where they would be on the Norwegian keyboard, I type these letters. It doesn't necessarily have to be the Capslock key, but it would be preferable as I never use it.

So like I said, I've been looking around a lot. I found the composeKey, but I really don't have time to press 2 or 3 different keys to produce the letters, since they're used frequently in Norwegian. I need it to be like pressing shift to make a capital letter. I found some threads that looked promising using xkb, but I couldn't make it work for Ubuntu 15.04.

Any help is deeply appreciated. If there is anything more you need to know, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this http://askubuntu.com/questions/422650/map-altgr-a-z-and-shift-altgr-a-z-to-greek-letter  can help you. I suggest using AltGr and use `xmodmap` (sometime you will have to restart it) or better define your own keyboard variant (see my answer, near the end).

Comment: How about switching to this layout: English (US, international with dead keys)?. It will allow you to type all of those using AltGr, although I'm not sure if their position on the keyboard would match a Norwegian keyboard.

Comment: @kos, I find that "English (international AltGr dead keys)" is really superior --- otherwise you will have the apostrophes changed to dead keys which is really a pain when programming... or when using `vim`.

Comment: @Rmano That's true. I don't get the rationale though. Double quotes at least are so used in any language, why switching them to an AltGr combo? stianste, what Rmano said, aside from programming or not "English (US, international with dead keys)" apparently moves double quotes to an AltGr combo, which I guess is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @kos --- no, you misunderstood me. In normal US international you use for example `'` as a dead key. `'` and `a` gives you `á`. To have a plain `'` you need to press `'` and space. In the layout I suggested, `'` is a plain `'`, and to have it acts as a dead key you need to press it *with* AltGr --- which I find much more natural.

Comment: @Rmano Apparently there are two ways of inserting `'` / `"`; the one you're mentioning (which I didn't know about) and AltGr + `'` and AltGr + SHIFT + `"`; either ways it's a pain, so incidentally I got you anyway. However yes, got double quote instead of apostrophe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it guys!

Short answer: Switched to English(Macintosh)

As user Kos suggested I switched the keyboard layout to English( International with dead keys). This worked, but unfortunately it doesn't have å. However, I messed around with different English keyboards and found that English(Macintosh) gives me æ ø å using AltGr + ', a and o respectively. This is going to take some getting used to, but at least I won't need to switch between to keyboards all the time. Thanks a lot for your help!